MongoDB: extract distinct values from a collection paging data
I need to extract from a collection the distinct values of "plate", that satisfy a filter.
The current pipeline is:
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "$and":[
            {
               "tenant":"aq"                   
            },
            {
               "timestamp":{
                  "$gte":1697407200000
               }
            },
            {
               "timestamp":{
                  "$lte":1697580059999
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "plate":1,
         "timestamp":1
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$plate"
      }
   },
   {
      "$skip":0
   },
   {
      "$limit":40
   }
]

If I don't use the data paging, the output of the aggregation is correct, but using the paging the result is pretty awkward: the second, the third and so on pages contain duplicates of plates returned from the previous ones.
I'm using a 4.2.20 mongodb in a production environment that, at the moment, cannot be updated, so if the problem is related to the mongo version I have to find a workaround.
Can you let me understand where I'm wrong?

since it looks like you are trying to get the distinct plates sorted. is it necessary to sort by timestamp as well. waht if you group first then sort liek https://mongoplayground.net/p/GxWK1ytaf_S

the reason you get things again is group doesnt give unique each time. so the sorting should happen after the group

ok, I'll try to move the sort after the group, leaving only the sort on the plate (_id to be precise).

What is the reason of { $skip: 0 }?

The $group stage does not guarantee the order of the results.  This means that subsequent runs can return the documents in a different order, so skipping the first few is quite likely to skip documents that weren't in the previous pages.  As @cmgchess mentioned, placing the sort after the group should solve that.

@cmgchess it worked! Thanks. If you want to write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Grouping can give different orders in each invocation so the effect of having a sort before a group becomes redundant. So it is important to do the sorting after the group stage.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        { "tenant": "aq" },
        { "timestamp": { "$gte": 1697407200000 } },
        { "timestamp": { "$lte": 1697580059999 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$plate" } },
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
  { "$skip": 0 },
  { "$limit": 40 }
])

playground
